# Can we ask about how to write reports

Tags: discussion

A lot of students, including myself, have to write lab reports for school. So I would like to ask, is questions regarding how to correctly write a good report allowed here (like how to correctly state a hypothesis, etc) or is it limited to pure physics only?

Comment: For general questions about research, try Academia.SE. For questions about phrasing, try the English Language & Usage SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my mind this would be a bad question for Physics SE because it is at once

- **Too general** There are many different level of detail, many different conventions that the instructor might want you to follow or to ignore. Some instructors expect a rigid report format some don't, and among those that do there is no universal agreement on what the format should be. Different instructors have different pet peeves about graphs; about the absolute necessity of including error bars (or not); about the need for at least seven data point to draw a line (or not) and so on. The level of detail expected in the report varies, as does the level of citation when you're talking about educational labs. Which mechanism should be used for reporting measurement uncertainties? Depends on the class and the instructor.

  This stuff is endless...
- **Too narrow** If you resolve the ambiguities then the question is only applicable to your particular situation and doesn't help anyone else (which is one of the goals of a good question).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what dmckee said, I see this site as being for questions about physics, and asking something about how to write a report is not a question about physics. So, no, I'd say it's off topic.

If you manage to find a question which is neither too broad nor too narrow, it might fit on another SE site, such as [Academia](//academia.stackexchange.com), [English Language & Usage](//english.stackexchange.com), or [Writers](//writers.stackexchange.com).